# Compute Literal Address from Segmented Address

Tags: linux, x86, segment

For example, say I have something like:

```
    0x33:0x10
```

and I want to get an address in the form:

```
    0x????????
```

from it. What is the easiest way to go about doing this? This is on Linux x86.

Comment: On 32 bits x86 or 64 bits x86-64 Linux systems there is only a flat address space! (no segmentation)

Comment: The why do I see in assembly code like gs:0x10?

Comment: The gs segment register is, IIRC, for thread local storage (but I could be wrong) on x86/32 bits, and it is not really a segment anymore, just a way of indexing...

Comment: There are also others such as ds:OFFSET, es:OFFSET, etc.

Comment: It would be useful to have a quick way of converting these to regular addresses.

Comment: Why are you asking? Most compilers rarely generate such code.

Comment: Really? I was looking @ PHPs source code in assembly using GDB and it was filled with such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The selector in the segment register is decoded to give a descriptor table specifier and a descriptor table index. The base given in the table and index is added to the offset in order to give a final address within process space.](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/s05_01.htm) In order to convert process memory to physical memory, [the page tables must be read and decoded.](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2005/readings/i386/s05_02.htm)